How to convert date string to localDate when the month is not abbreviated
I am trying to convert the date string that has full month name using LocalDate but I am getting java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 6
I tried looking online but can't find suitable solution.
public void iConvertDate() {
        String datevalue = String.valueOf(UIPgAct.dateFormat("10 March 2024", "dd MMM yyyy"));
    }

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public LocalDate dateFormat(String dateToFormat, String fromFormatPattern) {
        LocalDate dateLocal = null;
        if (dateToFormat != null) {
           try {
               DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(fromFormatPattern, Locale.US);
               dateLocal = LocalDate.parse(dateToFormat, dtf);
               break;
           } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
        }
        return dateLocal;
    }

I tried both "dd MMM yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy" formats and both of them returning the same error. I am stuck here.
Thanks

Have you tried with MMMM? Four Characters is usally for the long form and three for the medium form Mar instead of March.

For more information about what the number of letters means, see the documentation (e.g., "Text: The text style is determined based on the number of pattern letters used. Less than 4 pattern letters will use the short form. Exactly 4 pattern letters will use the full form. Exactly 5 pattern letters will use the narrow form. Pattern letters 'L', 'c', and 'q' specify the stand-alone form of the text styles").

If we want to parse full month name like 10 March 2024", We need to use
"dd MMMM yyyy" date formatter.
try with the below
LocalDate date= dateFormat("10 March 2024", "dd MMMM yyyy");
public LocalDate dateFormat(String dateToFormat, String fromFormatPattern) {
        LocalDate dateLocal = null;
        if (dateToFormat != null) {
            try {
                DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(fromFormatPattern, Locale.US);
                dateLocal = LocalDate.parse(dateToFormat, dtf);
                //break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return dateLocal;
    }

this will return Formated Date:2024-03-10
